# How to orientate an uploaded image from a mobile camera?

Tags: php, html, image

I'm having some issues with the image that is taken via a mobile camera and is then uploaded to my server. The function works fine with no issues, however depending on how the camera is facing the image comes out in an awkward way. All I want it to do is have the image round the correct way. I've attached an image to give you an example, the left side is how it is working at the moment and the right is how I want it to work. Any ideas?

**Image Example**

[image]

**PHP - ak_php_img_lib_1.0**

```
<?php
// Function for resizing jpg, gif, or png image files
function ak_img_resize($target, $newcopy, $w, $h, $ext) {
    list($w_orig, $h_orig) = getimagesize($target);
    $scale_ratio = $w_orig / $h_orig;
    if (($w / $h) > $scale_ratio) {
           $w = $h * $scale_ratio;
    } else {
           $h = $w / $scale_ratio;
    }
    $img = "";
    $ext = strtolower($ext);
    if ($ext == "gif"){ 
      $img = imagecreatefromgif($target);
    } else if($ext =="png"){ 
      $img = imagecreatefrompng($target);
    } else { 
      $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($target);
    }
    $tci = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
    // imagecopyresampled(dst_img, src_img, dst_x, dst_y, src_x, src_y, dst_w, dst_h, src_w, src_h)
    imagecopyresampled($tci, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w, $h, $w_orig, $h_orig);
    imagejpeg($tci, $newcopy, 80);
}
?>
```

**PHP - AttachImage**

```
if(isset($_FILES['UploadFileField'])){
        $allowed = array('jpg','png');
        $name = $_FILES["UploadFileField"]["name"];
        $tmp = $_FILES['UploadFileField']['tmp_name'];
        $type = $_FILES['UploadFileField']['type'];
        $newName = "Image Attachment.jpg";
        $types = array('jpg','png');
        $ext = pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        if(in_array($ext,$types)){
            move_uploaded_file($tmp, "UPLOADS/$newName");
            echo '<font size="3"><p align="center"><b>UPLOAD SUCCESSFUL: </font><font color="#000000" size="3">Your document has now been uploaded and is ready to send.</b></p></font>';

        include_once("ak_php_img_lib_1.0.php");
        $target_file = "UPLOADS/$newName";
        $resized_file = "UPLOADS/resized_$newName";
        $wmax = 200;
        $hmax = 200;
        ak_img_resize($target_file, $resized_file, $wmax, $hmax, $ext);

        }

        else {
            if(!$tmp){
                echo '<font size="3"><p align="center"><b>UPLOAD FAILED: </font><font color="#000000" size="3">No document has been selected.</b></p></font>';
            }

            else {
                echo '<font size="3"><p align="center"><b>UPLOAD FAILED: </font><font color="#000000" size="3">Uploaded document was an incorrect extension type, please use ".jpg" or ".png" only.</b></p></font>';
            }
        }
    }

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
        header( 'Location: Review.php' );
    }

    if (isset($_POST['delete'])){   
        if (file_exists("UPLOADS/Image Attachment.jpg")) {
            echo '<font size="3"><p align="center"><b>DETLEION COMPLETE: </font><font color="#000000" size="3">Image no longer available</b></p></font>';
            unlink('UPLOADS/Image Attachment.jpg');
            unlink('UPLOADS/resized_Image Attachment.jpg');
        } 

        else{
            echo '<font size="3"><p align="center"><b>DETLEION FAILED: </font><font color="#000000" size="3">No image available for Deletion</b></p></font>';
        }
    }
```

**HTML - AttachImage**

```
<body link="black">
    <div class="gridContainer clearfix">
        <div id="borderDiv">
            <div id="navDiv">
                <div id="backNavDiv">   
                    <a href="index.php?logout"><font color="white"><p align="right"><b>&nbsp;&lt;&nbsp;Log Out</b></p></font></a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="headerDiv">
                <p>Attach Image</p>
            </div>                

            <?php
                if (file_exists("UPLOADS/resized_Image Attachment.jpg")) {
                    echo '<div class="uploadImage"></div>';
                }

                else{
                    echo '<div class="loadingImage"></div>';
                }
            ?>

            <div id="loginBtnDiv">
                <div id="uploadAreaDiv">
                    <form action="AttachImage.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="FileUploadForm" id="FileUploadForm">
                    <label for="UploadFileField"></label>
                    <input type="file" name="UploadFileField" id="UploadFileField"/>
                    <input type="submit" name="UploadButton" id="UploadButton" value="Upload"/>
                    </form>     
                </div>

                <form action="AttachImage.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="delete" id="delete">
                    <input id="delete" name="delete" type="submit" value="Delete">
                </form>

                <form action="AttachImage.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="FileForm" id="FileForm">
                    <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Next">
                </form>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="logoDiv">
        <img src="IMAGES/Logo.png">
    </div> 
</body>
```

**CSS - Master**

```
.uploadImage { 
    background: url(../UPLOADS/resized_Image%20Attachment.jpg) 50% 50% no-repeat;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.loadingImage { 
    background: url(../IMAGES/loading.gif) 50% 50% no-repeat;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```